# Why can't the container display the content of mounting directory of host?

Tags: linux, docker, gitlab

I am using the following command to back up the `gitlab` repository data:

```
docker run --volumes-from gitlab_data -v $(pwd):/backup genezys/gitlab:7.5.2 tar cvf /backup/gitlab_data.tar /var/opt/gitlab /var/log/gitlab /etc/gitlab
```

Then I extract the backup data and run a new container to check whether the data is backed up successfully:

```
[root@localhost backup]docker run --name gitlab_data --volume /var/opt/gitlab --volume /var/log/gitlab --volume /etc/gitlab genezys/gitlab:7.5.2 /bin/true
[root@localhost backup]# docker run --detach --publish 8080:80 --publish 2222:22 --volumes-from gitlab_data genezys/gitlab:7.5.2
......
root@19f5c52a95af:/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/root# ls -alt
total 0
drwxrwx---. 2 git git  6 May  8 08:57 .
drwxrws---. 3 git git 17 May  8 08:57 ..
```

There is no content in `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/root` directory.

But actually, I can find content on host:

```
[root@localhost git-data]# cd /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/root
[root@localhost root]# ls -alt
total 8
drwxrwx---. 4 polkitd ssh_keys   41 May  8 04:47 .
drwxrwx---. 8 polkitd ssh_keys 4096 May  8 04:47 test.git
drwxrwx---. 8 polkitd ssh_keys 4096 May  8 04:47 test.wiki.git
drwxrws---. 3 polkitd ssh_keys   17 May  8 04:42 ..
```

Why can't the container display the content of mounting directory of host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not mapping any host directories to container besides /backup.
`--volume /var/opt/gitlab` creates new volume, if you want to map directory, use `--volume /var/opt/gitlab:/var/opt/gitlab` syntax - https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems